# Can I reduce this Passport code?

Tags: javascript, passport.js

This is more of a conceptual question as logically, I can reduce the code below.  Per the comments, user information is extracted and put in `props`.  The same user data was then pulled from the database to be returned using `done`.

I think the original author of the code wanted to make sure it was saved to the database.  But I think that is overkill.

Error checking will let us know if anything went wrong and we don't need to pull the data immediately after saving it.  We can just return the same data that was stored.

This is passport authentication code.

```
// the user was not found
// create the user, get the user, and return the user object
function createUser (done, profile) {
  let props = obtainProps(profile);
  DBM.createUser(props).then(() => {
    DBM.getUser(props.id_google).then((res) => {
      return done(null, res[0]);
    }).catch( error => {
      return done(error, null);
    });
  });
}
```

to this code:

```
// the user was not found
// create the user then return props
function createUser (done, profile) {
  let props = obtainProps(profile);
  DBM.createUser(props).then(() => {
    return done(null, props);
  }).catch( error => {
    return done(error, null);
  });
}
```

Comment: So... DBM.createUser does not add any extra fields, indices etc? Otherwise, res[0] and props are not identical.

Comment: Good point.  I left out an important part and that is the actual set of data used for rendering the UI.  It does add a timestamp but it is not used in the UI.

Comment: Why don’t you just return the promise?

Comment: @baao - can you elaborate ?

Comment: Do not use callbacks when you have promises. Drop the `done` parameter and instead `return` the promise that `then` gives you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can omit the check too, in addition, as commented, it would make sense to use the Promise and return that, instead of passing a callback and execute it in the promise's `then`. Promises were made to replace callbacks, your code is going in the other direction. Your createUser function should look like

```
function createUser (profile) {
  let props = obtainProps(profile);
  return DBM.createUser(props);
}
```

and if you need the result somewhere else, chain the function with `then`

```
// somewhere else in your code
createUser().then(e => /* e is result of DBM.createUser */)
```

Comment: The OP's code doesn't handle any errors either, so I doubt the `.catch()` is necessary

Comment: Yeah, they mentioned the wanted to introduce error handling though. I've edited the answer to explain that better

Comment: I think they meant doing error handling in the `done` callback, so the equivalent would be putting the `.catch()` outside of the call

Comment: Hm, you're right. I think returning the synchronous retrieved `props` from the promise wouldn't be good style - it should be retrieved before the call to createUser, so I didn't use the then() within createUser's promise - do you second? @Bergi

Comment: I have no idea what that `DBM` is actually doing.